# For a holomorphic 1-form $f dz= (u+iv) dz$, multiplicity of $f$=winding number of loop $u,-v$

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $\alpha$ be a holomorphic 1-form on a Riemann surface $X$ s.t. 
\begin{align*} \alpha \vert _p=0 \\  f dz=(u+iv) dz \textit{   on U}  \end{align*}$(U, \varphi)=(U, z)$ ia a coordinate disk centered at $p$ such that $\alpha$ does not vanish on $U-p$.

Then $f$ is a holomorphic function thus has an integer multiplicity, say $n$. 
$u,-v:\varphi^{-1}(S^1)\to \mathbb{R}^2 -0 $ is a closed loop and thus has an integer winding number around $0$, say $m$.

How can I show that $n=m$?

Comment: Isn't this essentially the argument principle? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle